# How to be device specific when running layout and layout-w720dp?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I happen to have an activity with different layouts for a phone and a tablet as `res/layout/activity_main.xml` and `res/layout-w720dp/activity_main.xml`. Now I want it to be device specific and not run the tablet version of the activity on all tablets. Is there a way I can specify that in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` or should I rename my activities for the phone and the tablet and use the following instead?

```
if (isTablet) { 
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tablet);
} else { 
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_phone);
}
```

Comment: device specific? how do you plan to maintain that? new tablets out all the time, if different codenames. sounds like it wouldnt be fun. its possible, but to maintain it is sketchy

Comment: @soldforapp I agree, I just want to not use the `layout-w720dp` of activity_main.xml on one specific tablet and use the phone version instead, is there I way I can avoid that?

Comment: Whatever tablet it is.... U need to find out the codename of it. For example, the pixel codename is Marlin. So if device == codeman... Blah blah

Comment: @soldforapp sounds like a good approach, thanks!